# Copy content from a file to add into a shell script file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I want to copy multiple lines from a file to a shell script (i.e. not an "ordinary" file).

For example:

- source file `A.txt`

  ```
    'ab cd'
    'ef gh'
    'ij kl'
  ```
- target script file `script.sh`

  ```
  ....
  ....
  list=(
    HERE I NEED TO COPY AND PASTE THE CONTENT FROM a.TXT file. 
   )
  ```
- The result should look like this:

  ```bash
  ....
  ....
  list=(
    'ab cd'
    'ef gh'
    'ij kl'
  )
  ```

The shell script should copy and paste automatically the content from another file to a script file. Kindly help me to resolve this

Comment: Do I understand correct that you want the running `script.sh` to modify the file `script.sh`? As a shell script is basically text, this task is not different from modifying other text files. Do you expect the change to have an effect on the execution of the script? The latter is normally not the case unless you somehow re-run the script. How exactly should the script determine where to put the contents of `A.txt`? Replace every line that contains `HERE I NEED TO COPY AND PASTE THE CONTENT FROM a.TXT file.` with the contents of the file?

Comment: Which shell specifically? In bash, you can fill an array from a file using the [readarray](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray) builtin with input redirection

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to modify the script file (possibly introducing a code injection vulnerability if the data in `A.txt` contains anything but nicely quoted lines). It would be trivial to write the script in such a way that it reads the contents of `A.txt` into the array `list` using `readarray -t list <A.txt`, provided you were using `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed -e '/list=(/ {N; s/\n.*$//; r A.txt' -e '}' script.sh
    ....
    ....
    list=(
    'ab cd'
    'ef gh'
    'ij kl'
     )
```

If `list(=` is encountered, the next line is appended and deleted, then the `A.txt` file appended to output.

Comment: after added those lines in a script, script should execute it but the lines are deleting before executing the scripts

Comment: @Beginner Simply write the result of the above command to a new file and execute that.